# Run confluence on docker with volume that has already files in it from last startup

Tags: docker, confluence, docker-for-windows

I start postgres via `docker-compose`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.15
    container_name: some-postgres
    volumes:
      -  postgresql-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=rw_dev
      - POSTGRES_USER=rw_dev
      - POSTGRES_DB=rw_development
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
    postgresql-volume:
      external: true
```

With commands:

```
docker volume create --name postgresql-volume -d local
docker-compose up -d
```

I start `confluence` via command:

```
docker run -v  E:\tmp\conflu:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence  --name="confluence" --env ATL_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/rw_development --env ATL_JDBC_USER=rw_dev --env ATL_JDBC_PASSWORD=rw_dev  --env ATL_DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver --env ATL_DB_TYPE=postgresql   --network devops_default --link some-postgres:some-postgres --link postgres:postgres -d -p 8090:8090 -p 8091:8091 atlassian/confluence-server
```

Now if i stop and remove `confluence` container and I am simulating situation when i want to restore `confluence` that has some files already i get an error when starting it via docker.

Normally it works fine on `http://localhost:8090/` but in this scenario i get `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on this website.

If i delete all files in `E:\tmp\conflu` directory, then stop/start confluence it works fine.
Kindly guide me why it can not work fine if it has some files already ?

Thanks

`docker logs confluence` last lines give me:

```
07-Nov-2019 12:23:10.841 WARNING [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [AtlassianEvent::CustomizableThreadFactory-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
07-Nov-2019 12:23:10.874 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
07-Nov-2019 12:23:10.903 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [215,140] milliseconds
```

Comment: did you install any plugins before deleting the containers ?

Comment: No, it was clean install of `confluence`. I also installed `Jira` on docker and it was connected to the same `DB`. I only created some dummy data on `Confluence` like new page.

Comment: buckup and restore should be done like this :https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/backing-up-data-861253815.html you can not simply try to re-deploy using the same data files

Comment: So `Confluence` docker image has to start always with empty volume folder? To my knowledge this image needs an volume.

Comment: yes after the configuration you can not start a new container from the same folder

Comment: So maybe it would be better to start it like that: `docker run -v  confluenceVolume:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence` and then i could delete is via `docker volume rm confluenceVolume` Please post  an answer so I can accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backup and restore should be done like [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/backing-up-data-861253815.html), you can not simply try to re-deploy using the same data files after configuring the instance